# Android Emulator Not Sending Sip Register Request To Server

Tags: android, sip, sip-server, jain-sip, mobicents-sip-servlets

I have build android Sip Stack on using IP address `10.0.2.2` and Port number `5060` and my mobicent-jbossAS7.2 sip-server is running on port `5080` (UDP and TCP both).

I have set the emulator 5554 redirect by using following commands.

`telnet localhost 5554`

After connected

`redir add udp:5080:5060` OK
Now I run the application on emulator. I donot get the response.
I am using windows 7(32-bit).

Am I using the redir command correctly?
Correct my understanding please,if I am wrong.
5080 on redir command is the port of development machine and 5060 is the emulated system.

Comment: Hard to tell whats going on. You should post debug logs or pcaps.

Comment: I have to set OUTBOUND_PROXY of emulator localhost? I am sending request to server on IP-Address 127.0.0.1:5080/udp and my Sip Stack is on port 5060. Now can you tell me about how I make redir cammand? Thanks in Advance.(I am confuse,I am sorry for being unprofessional)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake that I was doing was, `redir` command was redirecting wrong. Since I have to redir from emulator(5070 Port) to server(5080 Port).

I change to this

```
redir add udp:5070:5080
```

instead of

`redir add udp:5080:5070`

Since I have to recieve response from server therefore server has to redirect my packets to my emulator.
[here](http://iomem.com/archives/23-Redirecting-TCP-and-UDP-traffic-to-the-Android-emulator.html), the link I solved my problem